# Alternate to Facebook login authentication iFrame

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

I am new to Facebook app development. I need to integrate Facebook with my website. On investigation ( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login ), I found that to access Facebook user informations, users need to authenticate and authorize my app through the Facebook authentication iFrame.

Is there any other way such that I can get the Facebook users - username and password in 2 text fields (HTML) and pass them to any api or scripts, so that both authentication and authorizing are done in the background automated way (alternate to Facebook login authentication iFrame).

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to like the answer, but it is the correct answer.  No you cannot, you'd be in violation of Facebook Policy.  It is very clear on this subject:

http://developers.facebook.com/policy/ See section I and item 2.